# How can I cancel an FTP transmission?

Tags: c#, chilkat, chilkat-ftp

I made a client for my brother in law to use to download files from me easily, and I wanted to add the ability to cancel a download.  I can't seem to figure it out though; how do you do it?  I saw there is an "AbortCurrent" on the FTP object, but it's not a method.

Comment: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csFtp2Ref.html Read the documentation carefully. You just need to set `AbortCurrent` to `true` and see what happens next.

Comment: Ahhh, OK.  Thanks a lot!